# Inserting keyword in Suite Setup/Teardown, Test Setup/Teardown in robot framework

Tags: python, automation, automated-tests, robotframework, rpa

I want to allow the user to write a test suite in robot syntax using our pre-defined custom keywords and run it, when it begins running I would like to insert certain custom keywords defined by us into suite setup / teardown and test setup / teardown without having to explicitly write it in every robot file as it is common across all files.

I'm not sure how to do so, but I think listeners is what i'm looking for but not entirely sure. can anyone guide me on how to do this?

Comment: Yes, that's achievable by listeners, but show your attempt so far, and what issues are you facing.

Comment: I would add custom keywords with grep before running the test.